# Prediction in a linear mixed model in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Consider the sleepstudy data in the lme4 package as shown below. The contains 18 subjects with repeated measurements of Reaction (Reaction is the response) taken on different days.

```
library("lme4")
head(sleepstudy)
  Reaction Days Subject
1 249.5600    0     308
2 258.7047    1     308
3 250.8006    2     308
4 321.4398    3     308
5 356.8519    4     308
6 414.6901    5     308
```

The following code fits a linear mixed model with a random intercept.

```
fit1 = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
```

We can obtain subject-specific random intercept using "ranef(fit1)". Also, one can use "predict(fit1)" to give predictions of the response for all the time points in the original data.

However, I would like to predict the response (Reaction) in R for the 18 subjects at Day=12 and Day 14 (Day 12 and 14 are days that are not in the original data but would like to make a prediction for Reaction).
That is, I should end up with a dataset that looks like this.

```
 Days  Subject  Predicted_Response
  12     308        
  12     309
  ...
  12     371
  12     372

  14     308        
  14     309
  ...
  14     371
  14     372
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can accomplish this with the "newdata" argument of the `predict` method:

```
library("lme4")
fit1 = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
newdata <- expand.grid(
  Days = c(12, 14),
  Subject = unique(sleepstudy$Subject)
)

newdata$Predicted_Response <- predict(fit1, newdata = newdata)

   Days Subject Predicted_Response
1    12     308           417.7962
2    14     308           438.7308
3    12     309           299.1630
4    14     309           320.0976
5    12     310           313.9040
6    14     310           334.8385
7    12     330           381.4190
8    14     330           402.3536
9    12     331           387.2287
10   14     331           408.1633
11   12     332           385.2338
12   14     332           406.1683
... etc ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to predict for two different days for an individual instead of one day. But this does answer my initial question.

Comment: Edited to show how we can use `expand.grid` to easily create the crossings between multiple Subjects and Days.